# Rails 5 API mode with ActionDispatch::Cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails 5 API that I need to use the `cookies` method for.

I need to store a cookie used by the front-end with some basic user data (not server session state).

I have this in my `application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActionDispatch::Cookies
```

It shows up properly when I call `rake middleware`

But this still happens...

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `cookies' for #<SessionsController:0x007fe96fd671e8>):
```

**Controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def login
    ...
    add_login_headers(current_company.id, user.id, user.format_rights)
    ...
  end

  private

  def add_login_headers(company_id, user_id, rights)
    ...

    cookies.permanent[Settings.cookies.app] = {
      value: JSON.generate(company_id: company_id, user_id: user_id, rights: rights),
      secure: true
    }
  end

end
```

Comment: can you provide action from controller where you use `cookies` method?

Comment: Added controller code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've fixed this kind of a ghetto way, just so I don't have to include 50,000 extra helpers.

```
def cookies
  # helpers not available in --api mode
  request.cookie_jar
end
```

Answer (score 6):

you need to add this Controller Module:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Cookies
```